# USB3 super-speed signals without USB2 D+/D-

Tags: usb

Hello StackOverflow community,

I've been stuck on the following problem for a bit and would greatly appreciate a bit of help. I apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge about USB in general:

My goal is to use a USB3 port to transmit super-speed data between a computer and another device without having to use the D+/D- USB2 pairs (the reason is that I have 2 optical fibers only!) . In practice imagine an active optical cable which would only be able to transmit the USB 3 super-speed signals -> no D+/D-... both sides of the active cable are of course powered individually. The active cable has on both sides as I/O the copper differential pairs of the super-speed signal as well a source of power.

Both ends of this link are an issue for me at this stage: on computer side is there a way to tweak some kind of USB3 driver to ignore the typical host-device construct which I understand is imposed by the underlying USB2 protocol - a kind of by-pass? On device side... well same thing I guess - I haven't yet figured out implementation option.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Grégory

Comment: Maybe post this on [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)?  This site is more focused on programming language based problems

Comment: Good answer on similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297031/usb-3-x-ss-enumeration)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.